# Hide div when no mysql value retrieved

Tags: jquery

I found several solutions for hiding divs when they are empty but not in connection with a mysql retrieved value.

```
<button class="platform_category" id="platform_', $platform['platform_id'],'_category"><a href="', $platform['platform_url'],'" target="_tab">', $platform['platform_category1'],'</a></button>
```

Jquery does not hide div when there is no data in mysql-row because it  thinks $platform['platform_category1'] is a value even though that is only the php-code to retrieve the mysql value in case there is one.

For the hiding jquery code I am using this:(if I replace the == with != it hides)

```
    $(function() {
    $('.platform_category').each(function() {
        if ($(this).html() == "") {
             $(this).hide();
       }
    }); 
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Buttons with class `platform_category` have `<a>` tag as inner html, so `html()` method does not make any sense here (it will always return `<a>`). Try `text()` instead:

```
$('.platform_category').each(function() {
    if ($(this).text() == "") {
        $(this).hide();
    }
});
```

**GOOD NOTE** (from [@Blazemonger](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10999209/hide-div-when-no-mysql-value-retrieved/10999295#comment14371987_10999295)): It is good to use text trimming with `$.trim()` method:

```
if ($.trim($(this).text()) == "") {
    $(this).hide();
}
```

Comment: Might want to `$.trim()` the `.text()` just to be on the safe side.

Answer (score 1):

I would use filter to check the content of the `.platform_category`. See below,

```
$(function() {
   $('.platform_category').filter(function() {
       return $.trim($(this).text()) == '';
    }).hide();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that $('.platform_category') isn't actually empty, because there is always an anchor tag in the div.

You could do this two ways, either via PHP (the best) or via JavaScript

Via PHP

```
   if ($platform['platform_category1'] != "") {
     <button class="platform_category" id="platform_', $platform['platform_id'],'_category">
        <a href="', $platform['platform_url'],'" target="_tab">',$platform['platform_category1'],'</a>   
      </button>
```

If you have to do it via JavaScript

```
    $(function() {
    $('.platform_category').each(function() {
        if ($(this).find('a').html() == "") {
             $(this).hide();
       }
    }); 
});
```

Answer (score -1):

```
$('.platform_category').each(function() {
    if ($.trim( $(this).text() )  ==  "") {
        $(this).hide();
    }
});
```